# packaging synced folder with vagrant base box

Tags: vagrant

when packaging a vagrant box, the package.box file does not contain a synced folder /src that has a bunch of repos I downloaded to it during provisioning. What would be the best way to include the synced folder so I can distribute the vm?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am experiencing it as well!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using shared folders between your host and your virtual machine. Vagrant package will never package your shared folders because they are not part of the virtual machine, they belongs to your host.

The best way to package these files, is to store them in another folder in the virtual machine like in your /home or /opt for example.